# Assign value to combobox Item populated from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I'm making an order form so customers can select what pizza and toppings they would like and be able to calculate a total for them.

I'm using a single dimensional array to populate the combobox with the pizza size choices:

string[] PizzaSize = { "Small $5.00", "Medium $7.00", "Large $9.00" };

and loading the information during the form load:

cboSize.DataSource = PizzaSize;

How can I assign values to the different sizes in the array and store that in a decimal variable? I'm using decimals because other items on the order form aren't exact dollar amounts, including tax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<String, Decimal> grandFunkers = GetGrandFunkers();
grandFunkers.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
grandFunkers.DisplayMember = "Key";
grandFunkers.ValueMember = "Value";

public static Dictionary<string, Decimal> GetGrandFunkers()
{ 
    Dictionary<string, string> grandFunk = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Mark Farner", 99.42},
        {"Don Brewer", 97.76},
        {"Mel Schacher", 88.39},
        {"Craig Frost", 71.87}
    };
    return grandFunk;
}
```

You will have to convert the cats from the greatest rock-'n'-roll band ever (sorry, Stones!) to pizza sizes.